# ROS-PocketSphinx: Getting the probabilities of the words

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use PocketSphinx to do voice recognition. For example I use a language model like this:

```
Hello
Hi
World
Earth
```

I say "Hello world", now I want the list of the probabilities/scores of the recognition. Like for the first word "Hello" a possible match could be:

```
"Hello" 90%
"Hi" 10%
"World" 30%
"Earth" 30%
```

I don't know how PocketSphinx represents the probabilities. It is only an example. Has someone a clue?
I use this example https://github.com/mikeferguson/pocketsphinx/blob/indigo-devel/nodes/recognizer.py

Thanks

Mosa

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205079/ros-pocketsphinx:-getting-the-probabilities-of-the-words/) by [Mosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/21181/mosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You asked the same question on stack overflow and Nikolay had posted an answer there.
So, I am just adding a link to that post so that others may find his apt answer.
[Correct answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577739/pocketsphinx-getting-the-probabilities-of-the-words)
---x---
**The answer says the following:**
"You can retrieve individual segments of hypothesis with iterator:
`print 'Best hypothesis segments: ', [(seg.word, seg.prob) for seg in decoder.seg()]`

seg.prob contains the confidence score. To have a meaningful confidence score you need to make sure your language model is large enough."
---x---
Also, there is an updated version of pocketsphinx available for ROS. You can find it here:
https://github.com/Pankaj-Baranwal/pocketsphinx/
You should use that instead.

---

Originally posted by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) with karma: 96 on 2017-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-09**:
Its the "uttid" value in partial_result() and final_result() of recognizer.py, also see 
[Using PocketSphinx with GStreamer and Python](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/gstreamer/)

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-09**:
Do you have any explanation why your linked repository should be used instead?

**Comment by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) on 2017-10-09**:
It has updated pocketsphinx features like kws mode, grammar mode etc, has much better wiki, a blog post to explain everything and is being maintained actively
Doesnt need external dependencies like GStreamer
CMUSphinx endorses it: https://github.com/cmusphinx/ros-pocketsphinx
MaxCharLimitReached

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-30**:
So I guess what that means is that the gstreamer plugin needs some updates?

**Comment by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) on 2017-10-31**:
If that's what you got from all of that, then there's nothing left to say.
I just sometimes wish there were as many active code-maintainers in the community as there are [fusspots.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fusspot?a=british)

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-31**:
verbose please?